# Does c# or vb.net produce module constructor under any circumstances?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

As the title says, does c# or vb.net produce a **module constructor** for an assembly under any circumstances or when particular code pattern is used?

EDIT: **To be clear, I am not looking for ways to add/use a module constructor.** I just want to know if the compilers produce/output a module constructor if some particular code pattern is used, maybe as a way to implement some specific language feature, etc.

Comment: Why do you need a 'module constructor'? What would that help you achieve? Understanding that may help people offering answers..

Comment: I had to google this, as I had never heard of it--and the first hit was to the reflection API.  I can only infer that CLR supports module constructors, but they are not exposed in C# other than via reflection.  I am not confident enough to say it as an official answer, but given this, and given that modules are not a C# concept (classes and namespaces and projects are), I suspect that C# never generates module constructors.   VB I don't know well enough to even speculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per

http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/

the answer is "No."  He goes on to describe a use case where he cared, and how he worked around the restriction by using Mono.

Comment: His article answers your question--its no.